# Export audio input from local machine to remote robot?

Tags: ros, audio, ssh, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working with a turtlebot2 and the sound drivers, specifically the jack server, are broken and I've already spent hours trying to fix them.  My local computer, however, has working sound drivers and I was wondering if there was a way to export the audio input functionality from the robot to the computer.  In other words, I want to be able to speak into a mic connected to my computer, have the audio processed by my computer, and then any nodes on the robot requiring that audio input will receive it over ssh.  I already have the ROS_MASTER_URI set to the remote robot and I am able to run rviz from my computer and control navigation of the robot.  Any ideas?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229276/export-audio-input-from-local-machine-to-remote-robot?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are you doing with the audio?

If you're doing speed recognition, you could run the ROS speech recognition node on your desktop, with the ROS_MASTER_URI set to the turtlebot, and its ROS messages could be subscribed to by any node on the turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-16**:
I am trying to run pocketsphinx so this would work.  However, when I try to run the robocup.launch from the pocketsphinx package, I get the error  "ImportError: No module named pygtk".  pygtk2 is installed on both the computer and the robot so I am not sure why it cannot find the module.

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-16**:
The issue might be that my PYTHONPATH and my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH are not set correctly but I have no idea how I would fix this.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-16**:
Which version of ROS and Linux are you running? How did you install pocketsphinx, from source or through apt?

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-17**:
Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.  I installed pocketsphinx through apt-get and made sure it was part of the indigo distribution.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-17**:
Sounds like an issue with pocketsphinx. You may want to ask a new question or file a bug report. It really should work out of the box if you installed it through apt.